# Using an SDK, their header files are using typedefs that do not name a type

Tags: c++, eclipse, byte, typedef

I'm using a SDK for a fingerprint scanner and I've added all of their header files to my project. In the header files they use a whole lot of typedefs that don't seem to work. I'm using Eclipse and am wondering if it is the issue.

For Example in the following:

```
#ifdef WIN32
typedef __int8    SecuAPI_SINT8;
typedef __int16   SecuAPI_SINT16;
typedef int       SecuAPI_SINT32;
typedef __int64   SecuAPI_SINT64;

typedef BYTE    SecuAPI_UINT8    ;
typedef WORD    SecuAPI_UINT16   ;
typedef DWORD     SecuAPI_UINT32;
```

BYTE, WORD, DWORD throw the error do not name a type.

The others seem to be okay. I tried adding the winDef.h and windows.h headers and that didn't seem to work.

Further down the code

```
typedef BOOL      SecuAPI_BOOL;
typedef CHAR      SecuAPI_CHAR;
typedef LPSTR     SecuAPI_CHAR_PTR;
```

Also throw the same error.

The other typdefs such as char, short, int, etc. seem to work.

EDIT:
I'm new to C so I don't know why but I copied and pasted their header files into new header files (because it wasn't letting me edit theirs) and The `BOOL, BYTE, WORD` types were now okay but the `__int8, __int16, etc.` didn't work. I added `<stdint.h>`and now all are working.

Thanks all!

Comment: #include windows.h ugliness (defines) before

Comment: What compiler/platform are you using? The `typedef`s are enclosed in an `#ifdef WIN32` block, which needs to be defined when the code is compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BOOL`, `CHAR`, `LPSTR` and similar entirely-capitalized-types are (usually) [Microsoft-defined types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx). The documentation states which headers are needed in order to get the correct definitions.